# How can I set a value to myself's variable in an ask other turtles[ ] block

Tags: simulation, modeling, netlogo

So I have this current setup

```
 ask turtles [                               ;i want this turtle (myself)
    ask other turtles [                      ;to ask other turtle, one by one (self)
      if Smin < Sim myself self [            ;to run a function wherein 
       ifelse Sim myself self < Smax         ;if Smin < Sim myself self < Smax
       [ ;if block ]                         ;self will be assigned to the variable
       [ ;else block ]                       ;of myself called 'Ac'
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could `ask myself [ set Ac myself ]`, but this is a bit confusing. (The referent of `myself` changes every time you enter an `ask` block, so `myself` is used twice to refer to two different agents.)

What I would suggest is to assign more explicit variable names to your agents. `self`/`myself` are convenient for simple code, but you don't *have* to use them all the way:

```
ask turtles [              
  let t1 self
  ask other turtles [      
    let t2 self
    if Smin < Sim t1 t2 [  
      ifelse Sim t1 t2 < Smax   
        [ ask t1 [ set Ac t2 ] ]
        [ ] ; do something else?
    ]
  ]
]
```